# Potential threat analysis classification (IP address)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, decision-tree, knn

I want to classify an IP address as either bad, neutral or good. I have 3 parameters i.e.

1. Is the IP address from a cloud provider like DigitalOcean (could be true or false only) ? if so, we penalize it.
2. Is the IP a known VPN/proxy (could be true or false only), we again penalize it.
3. Is the IP originating from a shady subnet (trust score in percentage)? We penalize it.

At first I wanted to use a credit score kind of weight measure approach i.e. the 3 conditions each carry 5 points. Each individual parameter would have a percentage rating, so if its a cloud provider we give it a 10/100 otherwise we can say give it 100/100.

The problem is that this approach would result in false negatives and optimizing the overall weight classification ranges would also be a problem.

Also differences in score ranges would be an issue. For example in a cloud provider could either be true or false, whereas a shady domain could have individual scores based on existing data.

What would be a more sane approach at tackling this? Would a decision tree be good enough or should I opt for KNN?